# Get a collision free hash for a specific query or a view with SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, hash, synchronization, hash-collision

I am working on a project where I need to synchronize data from our system to an external system. What I want to achieve, is to periodically send only changed items (rows) from a custom query. This query looks like this (but with many more columns) :

```
SELECT T1.field1,
    T1.field2,
    T1.field2,
    T1.field3,
    CASE WHEN T1.field4 = 'some-value' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    T2.field1,
    T3.field1,
    T4.field1
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.pk = T2.fk
INNER JOIN T3 ON T3.pk = T2.fk
INNER JOIN T4 ON T4.pk = T2.fk
```

I want to avoid to have to compare every field one to one between synchronizations. I came with the idea that I could generate a hash for every row from my query, and compare this with the hash from the previous synchronization, which will return only the changed rows. I am aware of the [CHECKSUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms189788.aspx) function, but it is very collision-prone and might miss changes sometimes. However I like the way I could just make a temp table and use `CHECKSUM(*)`, which makes maintenance easier (not having to add fields in the query and in the CHECKSUM) :

```
SELECT T1.field1,
    T1.field2,
    T1.field2,
    T1.field3,
    CASE WHEN T1.field4 = 'some-value' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    T2.field1,
    T3.field1,
    T4.field1
INTO #tmp
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.pk = T2.fk
INNER JOIN T3 ON T3.pk = T2.fk
INNER JOIN T4 ON T4.pk = T2.fk;

-- get all columns from the query, plus a hash of the row
SELECT *, CHECKSUM(*)
FROM #tmp;
```

I am aware of [HASHBYTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms174415.aspx) function (which supports sha1, md5, which are less prone to collisions), but it only accept varchar or varbinary, not a list of columns or * the way CHECKSUM does. Having to cast/convert every column from the query is a pain in the ... and opens the door to errors (forget to include a new field for instance)

I also noticed [Change Data Capture and Change Tracking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) features of SQL Server, but they all seems complicated and overkill for what I am doing.

So my question : is there an other method to generate a hash from a query or a temp table that meets my criterias ?

If not, is there an other way to achieve this kind of work (to sync differences from a query)

Comment: You may want to look at [`ROWVERSION`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx?ppud=4). If you track the last value processed then you can periodically check for newer values.

Comment: ROWVERSION is binded to a table, not a query or a view. And also, it gets updated if any of the field of a row is updated, that's not what I want, I want to check for changes on a set of columns (from more that one table with joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do exactly what I wanted, thanks to the `FOR XML` clause :

```
SELECT T1.field1,
    T1.field2,
    T1.field2,
    T1.field3,
    CASE WHEN T1.field4 = 'some-value' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    T2.field1,
    T3.field1,
    T4.field1
INTO #tmp
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON T2.pk = T2.fk
INNER JOIN T3 ON T3.pk = T2.fk
INNER JOIN T4 ON T4.pk = T2.fk;

-- get all columns from the query, plus a hash of the row (converted in an hex string)
SELECT T.*, CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), HASHBYTES('sha1', (SELECT T.* FOR XML RAW)), 2) AS sHash
FROM #tmp AS T;
```